# Why jsHint doesn't detect an error "is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I tried to use jsHint on my project. But for me it doesn't work obviously. For example:

```
(function () {
    if (!window.myApp) window.myApp = {};
    var myApp = window.myApp;
    var a = function (key) {
        key = key || "key";
        return myApp.someModule.get(key);
    };

    a();
})();
```

This chunk should throw error, something like that: "TypeError: myApp.someModule is undefined", but jsHint is still silent. I use default settings for jsHint from http://jshint.com/ . Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you have not set the `undef` option? Have a look a the documentation: http://www.jshint.com/options/

Answer (score 1):

Fairly sure that it only checks for variables in the "local" scope, it won't check all the way down objects chains. In fact I'd say it's impossible to be able to detect in all cases.

Consider:

```
var o = {};
someAjaxRequest({
    callback: function(response) { 
        o[response.responseText] = 'found!';
    }
});
```

Comment: It so strange, isn't it? :) But apperantly this is the reason. Thanks!

Comment: Not really, it would be pretty close to impossible to totally figure it out without actually running the code. I'll update my post with an example.

Comment: I think, jsHint should detect situation when method of some object is undefined. In your example, if i add string `var a = o["h"].method();` it still undetected. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Sure, but the point is it's really difficult to catch it in all scenarios, especially with dynamic property assignment and the way object properties work, so it seems as though it doesn't try.